# Ghost config not loading correct database file

Tags: docker-compose, ghost-blog

I'm using a sqlite3 database file with my ghost blog with docker-compose. However when I start it the config file correctly copies over my database and theme to `/content` but it doesn't load in the browser. Instead it's loading the original database and theme from `/versions/3.32.1/content`.

I can get it working correctly when I `cp` the db file and theme folder to `/versions/3.32.1/content` and change the permissions of the db file but I'd like this to happen automatically. How can I adjust the config file or docker-compose to do this?

Here is my `config.development.json`:

```
{
    "url": "http://ghost:2368",
    "server": {
        "port": 2368,
        "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "database": {
        "client": "sqlite3",
        "connection": {
            "filename": "content/data/threadlet.db"
        },
        "debug": false
    },
    "paths": {
        "contentPath": "content/"
    },
    "privacy": {
        "useRpcPing": false,
        "useUpdateCheck": true
    },
    "useMinFiles": false,
    "caching": {
        "theme": {
            "maxAge": 0
        },
        "admin": {
            "maxAge": 0
        }
    }
}
```

and my ghost setup in docker-compose:

```
  ghost:
    image: ghost:latest
    container_name: ghost
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2368:2368
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      # DATABASE_URL: 
      url: "http://ghost:2368"
      NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./ghost/config.${NODE_ENV}.json:/var/lib/ghost/config.${NODE_ENV}.json
      - ./ghost/content:/var/lib/ghost/content
```

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem, it's weird. Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. I don't think docker-compose supports a `cp` command but what about another line in volume: `-./ghost/content:/var/lib/ghost/versions/3.32.1/content` ? I'm no longer using ghost but interested to find out if you find a fix

Comment: Yes, the easiest is to just use a absolute path, that's what I did.